# haproxy: extract host and port from req.hdr(host)

Tags: haproxy

I am using haproxy version 1.5.4.

req.hdr(host) provides host:port, ex: If I issue a request http://abc:9080, then req.hdr(Host) equals abc:8080, is there any way I can get only hostname or IP address, 1.1.1. if request is sent as http://1.1.1.1:9080

My use case is I want to use that IP/Host in redirecting to SSL port.

Your inputs appreciated.

With regards,

-N-

Comment: Any chance of an upgrade to 1.6?  The [`regsub()`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#7.3.1-regsub) (regular expression substitution) was first introduced there and should allow something similar to `req.hdr(Host),regsub(:[0-9]+$,)`.

Comment: While having the same need, I've figured out that `req.hdr(host),field(1,:)` might be a better choice compared to `regsub()`.